# Starting point of the series solution in the Frobenius method

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, power-series

My question is why doesn't the starting point of the series solution in the Frobenius method (usually $n=0$) increase by $1$ ($n=1$, $n=2$, etc.) when differentiating, but it remains the same?

To be more specific, compare statements (2), (3), (5) ($n$ increases by $1$ every time we differentiate) with statements (9), (11), (12) ($n$ remains $0$ when we do) in this link: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/FrobeniusMethod.html

Thanks.

Comment: Could you add some more detail? It's not obvious what you're actually asking about at present.

Comment: @Chappers I edited my post, hope it helps.

Comment: In the first set, the lowest term is constant. In the second, it's only constant if $k=0$ or $k=1$ (in which case the factors from the differentiation make it zero anyway).